# hot to make the text move to next line inside div when it covers the width of the div in css

Tags: css, html

hi how can i make the text inside div coming to the next line if the text covers the  width of contenteditable="true"

Just like gmail chat when some one writes anything inside div then it automatically moves to next line

I am talking about the contentEditable="true" div means the div in which we can edit or write text.

Comment: A div with a fixed width should do this already.

Comment: plz read the question again i edited it.

Comment: contentEditable is HTML5 only is it not, should have an 'html5' tag.  I believe it does wrap properly if the width is restricted either by a parent or by a width declartion on itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<p> when text exceeds width, continue in new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790170/p-when-text-exceeds-width-continue-in-new-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.break-word { 
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it is not enough using "word-wrap : break-word".

```
.break-word { 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:flex;
}
```