# <p> when text exceeds width, continue in new line

Tags: html, overflow

I have the following structure:

```
<ul>
<li>
<p style="width:10px;">
Text goes here
</p>
</li>
<li>
<p style="width:10px;">
Text goes here
</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

When the text of the p exceeds the 10px limit I would like it to continue in a new row.. How do i do that? Thanks

Comment: No I would like it to overflow per word

Comment: But that's what this example does. I thought you wanted each letter on a new line.

Comment: Wait a minute, you mean you want to spread the `p` over multiple list items? That's not possible. To do that, put each word in a list item of its own by hand (or with Javascript or something).

Comment: `overflow-wrap` property may be what you want if you're finding this question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059128/16940

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your example already word-wraps (because`<p>` is already a block element), if you want to break words, then you could try:

```
p.letters {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here's a basic working example: http://jsfiddle.net/G9z5M/ (see updates below).

You can play around with it using various techniques:

```
/* Wraps normally, on whitespace */
p.words {
    word-wrap: normal;
}    

/* Hides non-wrapped letters */
p.hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Outputs a single line, doesn't wrap at all */
p.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}​
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G9z5M/1/

Answer (score 10):

For me it worked

```
white-space: initial;
```

May be it helps to someone else.

Comment: This works, when combined with `max-width: Xpx`.

Answer (score 4):

Normaly `p` elements are block so the `width` is respected, and it should wrap at 10 pixels.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ejLmu/

If it does not work for you it means that you have some css rules that override the default settings. You either have set `display:inline` (*in which case the width is not respected*), or a `white-space:nowrap;` (*which disables the text-wrapping*).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sur I do understand your question but with CSS you shoudl try :

```
word-break: break-all; // normal; // keep-all;
```

And if you want to hide extra content :

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
style="width:10px; display: block;"
```

Comment: `p` already has `display:block`, so that won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap` is now legacy name for `overflow-wrap` as per CSS 3 specifications. See [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-css-word-wrap-overflow-wrap-word-break/) for reference.

So, to break a word so it doesn't overflow it's container width simply do:

```html
<p style="width:10px; overflow-wrap:break-word">this is a looooong line of text</p>
```